# Python print failing to print Unicode and string same time

Tags: python, unicode

The below are few cases I observed. Like to know why Python's print is behaving like this, and possible fixes.

```
>>> print "%s" % u"abc" # works
>>> print "%s" % "\xd1\x81" # works
>>> print "%s %s" % (u"abc", "\xd1\x81") # Error
```

For the above (last), I'm getting: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

But, this works

```
>>> print "%s %s" % ("abc", "\xd17\x81") # works
```

And when I do

```
>>> print "%s %s" % (u"abc", u"\u0441") # Error
```

Its raising `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0441' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 2):

When you mix Unicode strings and byte strings in Python 2, the byte strings are implicitly coerced to Unicode using the default `ascii` codec.  You will get `UnicodeDecodeError` if this fails.

When you print Unicode strings, they are implicitly encoded in the current output encoding.  You will get `UnicodeEncodeError` if this fails.

So:

```
>>> print "%s" % u"abc"
```

is really:

```
>>> print unicode("%s",'ascii') % u"abc" # and valid
```

But the following only works if you mean "doesn't throw an error".  If you expect it to print U+0441 character it will do so only if the output encoding is UTF-8.  It prints garbage on my Windows system.

```
>>> print "%s" % "\xd1\x81"
```

The following gives error because of the implicit Unicode decoding:

```
print "%s %s" % (u"abc", "\xd1\x81")
```

which is really:

```
print unicode("%s %s",'ascii') % (u"abc", unicode("\xd1\x81",'ascii'))
```

`\xd1` and `0x81` are outside the ASCII range of 0-7Fh.

The last error implies that your output encoding is not UTF-8, because it couldn't encode `\u0441` to a character supported by the output encoding for printing.  UTF-8 can encode all Unicode characters.

Comment: you should emphasize: "don't mix Unicode and bytestrings"

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. When you output, you have to encode your unicode object to the desired character encoding, i.e. `utf-8` or whatever.  Think of `unicode` (including all u"" literals) as an abstraction that has to be encoded to something like `utf-8` prior to serialisation.

You can encode a `unicode` object `s` to `utf-8` with `s.encode('utf-8')`. `str` objects in Python 2 are byte-encoded, therefore you do not get an error with things like "\xd17\81", they are already encoded.

I would recommend you to use Python 3 rather than Python 2 where this is a bit more intuitive.